# Bivariate normal distribution, the 5th parameter

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, bivariate-distributions

What does $\rho$ , the 5th parameter mean in the bivariate normal distribution ?

[image]

Comment: The random variables are correlated with $\rho$ as cor. coefficient.

Comment: @herbsteinberg What does this **correlation** mean for the bivariate distribution in words ?

Comment: Correlation definition: $\rho=\frac{E(X_1X_2)-\mu_1\mu_2}{\sigma_1\sigma_2}$.  Random variables need not be normal.

Comment: @herbsteinberg But the $\rho$ may be chosen in the bivariate distribution but in your case it is **computed** from it.

Comment: When the relationship between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is not given, $\rho$ defines the relationship.